# Emailing a log4net log as a System.Net.Mail.Attachment throws IOException (process locked)

Tags: c#, .net, email-attachments, system.net.mail

I wanted to send the current `log4net` log as an email attachment using `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` but when I pass in the file path an `IOException` is thrown.

```
Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(logPath);
```

> *The process cannot access the file 'C:\Log\log4net.log' because it is being used by another process*

The appender configuration looks like this:

```
<appender name="RootRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:\Log\log4net.log" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
    <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10024KB" />
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%username|%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Is there any way to get around this? Can I copy out the log file or somehow release it from the locking process?

Comment: What type of Appender are you using in the .config file can you post what this section looks like for starters 
`<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

using `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` will tell log4net to only lock the file for a brief moment while it is doing the actual writing. There is a slight performance penalty, but allows you to do things such as add it as an attachment a lot easier.

Otherwise log4net will lock the file indefiniately while the process is running.